# Entity-Relationship Diagram Redundancy: store, product, orders, categories

Tags: mysql, database, normalization, entity-relationship, database-normalization

I'm trying design a model which allows a user to be a buyer and seller with a single account, but some teachers told me that this diagram is wrong because it has redundancy.

I had reviewed the diagram but I haven't found a way to solve this redundancy. In the table `orders` I need to know who is a buyer, so for this reason I didn't delete this from the table. Some ideas?

[image]

Comment: There are no users in that diagram. Do you mean `Orders.buyer` and `Product.seller` both reference TBL_store? Like this is a business-to-business sales model? I don't see any redundancy there. You should ask your teacher to clarify which part has redundancy, or perhaps they could describe an anomaly that could occur due to the redundancy.

Comment: Yes, it is b to b, Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Unrelated to your question - but you might want to add quantities to `Product` and `OrderProduct`. And the case where 2 or more `seller`s exist for a product

Comment: [Please edit the corresponding DDL into your quesion.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Please edit clarifications into your question, not comments. PS "Redundant" is vague. Specific problems with designs do or don't involve things that can roughly be described by redundancy.  If your teacher said that then they are expecting you to follow a design method with steps that were associated with "redundancy". Tell us your assignment/specification, give us a reference to the method you are supposed to follow & show us how you are following it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that are "redundant" (not normalized to be exact) in your scheme is this :

[image: link table]

You don't need to make a special ID, a composite PK is enough.

```
-------------------
|   ORDERPRODUCT  |
-------------------
| PK | PRODUCT_ID |
| PK | ORDER_ID   |
-------------------

ADD CONSTRAINT pk 
PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_ID, ORDER_ID);
```

Comment: Ids have nothing to do with normalization, either to 1NF or higher.

Answer (score 0):

On top of what @Blag has said, for `Categories`, you have 2 fields that might do the same thing: `categoryname` and `description`. You already have an identifier with `PK_IdCategory`, so one of those might be unnecessary